# Return types of columns as strings sequelize

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, sequelize.js

I have defined models so I need to know what type their columns are

Because when I try to use `JSON.stringify(Book.getAttributes().id.type)` I get object like `{"options":{}}`, but I need a string like INTEGER.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Can you show the content of `JSON.stringify(Book.getAttributes()` and the model definition as well